# What is the range of $f(x) = \frac{x^2-5x+6}{x-3}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Consider $f(x) = \dfrac{x^2-5x+6}{x-3}$ . Our problem is finding range of $f$ . I  know that the way is assuming  $x \not = 3$ then $f(x) = x-2$ and put $x=3$ in the $f$ . So the range of $f$ is $\mathbb R- \{f(3) = 1\}$ but I think it's a contradiction . Because first of all we supposed that $x \not = 3$ and then we put $x = 3$ in the function! Why this is true ?

Comment: It is not that one supposes $x\neq 3$ but that $x=3$ is not in the domain of $f$ at all.

Comment: @Jack I think when we say $x \not = 3$ , it means that our function doesn't confirm $3$. So we can't put 3 .

Comment: $x=3$ is not in the [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) of $f$. It does not make sense to write $f(3)$ in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\;w\in\text{Im}\,(f)\;$ , then $\;x\neq3\;$ and :

$$w=\frac{x^2-5x+6}{x-3}=x-2\implies x=w+2\;\implies$$

we get that $\;w\;$ can be anything **but** whatever makes $\;x=w+2=3\implies w=1\;$ (since $\;x=3\;$ is *not* in the definition domain) , and thus Im$\,(f)=\Bbb R\setminus\{1\}\;$ .

Answer (score 1):

The function $f:\mathbb{R}\backslash\{3\}\to\mathbb{R}$ can be written as
$$
f(x)=\frac{(x-3)}{x-3}\cdot(x-2)=x-2,\quad x\neq3. 
$$
Hence the range of $f$ is
$$
\{x-2\mid x\in\mathbb{R},x\neq 3\}=\mathbb{R}\backslash\{1\}.
$$

Comment: If we want to find the $\lim_{x\to 3} f(x) $ we say that $\lim_{x\to 3} f(x) = 1$ but here it seems we are saying different thing.

Comment: @S.H.W: I don't understand the point of your comment.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ can be written as $f(x) = x - 2$ if $x \neq 3$ as you deduced correctly. This means that $Im(f) = \{x-2|x \neq 3\} = \mathbb{R} - \{1\}$